# Reindexing / rebuild Indexes on Linked Server tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index, linked-server

I am trying to run the below query to rebuild the index on a table on the Linked server, but it is not working. Can any one please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [LinkedServerName].[dbname].[dbo].[tablename] REBUILD 
WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90)
```

This is giving me below error:

> Cannot find the object "[LinkedServerName].[dbname].[dbo].[tablename]" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Answer (score 7):

Four-part-naming syntax is not supported for `ALTER INDEX`.

Try this:

```
EXEC ('ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbname].[dbo].[tablename] REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90);') 
AT LinkedServerName;
```

Comment: Or `EXEC LinkedServerName.dbname.sys.sp_executesql 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ...;');`